# Will there be a SSRS 2014/2016 reportviewer in ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportviewerformvc

Will there be a SSRS 2014/2016 Report Viewer in ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC 6?
In case No, any report viewer and/or reporting tools working with ASP.NET Core MVC 6 RTM?

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer this without being a Microsoft employee?

Comment: not necessarily to be MS guy, people like https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1528 offer solution but not complete :(

Answer (score 0):

I could use the SRSS on an asp.net core SPA app. But it took many not elegant hacks.

I was not satisfied with the result, but it works.

I was forced to include the reports and datasets in an old Class Library version for compatibility.